# Called function work at printf but not at arithmetic statement

Tags: c, function

I made a `struct Triangle` and I made a function to calculate `p(perimeter/2)`.
When I call the function inside `printf` it works.
But when I call the same function as a simple arithmetic statement it doesn't work and gives me following error

```
called object 'p' is not a function or function pointer
```

Source code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct{
       int a, b, c;
} Triangle;
    
int perimeter (Triangle t){
    return t.a + t.b + t.c;
}
    
float p (Triangle t){
    return perimeter(t) / 2.0;
}
    
int main() {   
    Triangle t = {3, 4, 5};
    //float p = p(t);
    printf("p = %.2f\n",p(t));
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: The answer is: don't give every single variable and function cryptic one-letter names. Give them meaningful names instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
float p = p(t);
```

defines a local variable `p` which shadows the global function `p`. This variable is of type `float`, so it is not a function or pointer.

Rename the variable to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

```
//float p = p(t);
```

You cannot use the same name for a function and a variable. Change your `float p` to `float a` and it should work. Or rename your function to, say `perimeter` instead of just `p`.

Also in general, it is better to use slightly longer, clear and descriptive names for functions.